# How to route an RSocket client in Flutter

Tags: flutter, spring-webflux, rsocket

this is java (webflux) code.

```
    public Mono<String> sendMessage(SendMessageRequest requestBody, RSocketRequester rSocketRequester) {
        Long userId = clientManager.getUserIdBySocket(rSocketRequester);

        Chat chat = Chat.builder()
                .chatroomId(requestBody.getChatroomId())
                .createdDate(LocalDateTime.now())
                .lastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.now())
                .userId(userId)
                .build();

        return chatRepository.save(chat)
                .flatMap(entity ->  chatReadRepository.findByUserIdAndChatroomId(userId, entity.getChatroomId()))
                .flatMapMany(entity -> chatMemberRepository.findAllByChatroomIdAndUserIdNot(entity.getChatroomId(), userId))
                .map(ChatMember::getUserId)
                .map(clientManager::getSocketByUserId)
                .flatMap(socketOptional ->
                    socketOptional.<org.reactivestreams.Publisher<String>>map(socketRequester -> socketRequester.route("chat.receive")
                        .data(requestBody)
                        .send()
                        .thenReturn("Success!"))
                        .orElseGet(() -> Mono.just("fail!"))
                )
                .collectList().thenReturn("Success!");
    }
```

I use this code In java

```
socketRequester -> socketRequester.route("chat.receive")
                        .data(requestBody)
                        .send()
                        .thenReturn("Success!"))
                        .orElseGet(() -> Mono.just("fail!"))
```

This is my flutter code. I use rsocket: ^1.0.0.

```
void main() async {
  String jwt = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiVVNFUiJdLCJpYXQiOjE2NTk1OTg1OTgsImV4cCI6MTY1OTYwODU5OH0.bJHn4IKm6DtnGAQAxyruRb-LJSgKt-72-L9g7JqBtHw";
  var rSocket = await RSocketConnector.create()
      .setupPayload(routeAndDataPayload("socket.acceptor", jwt))
      .connect('tcp://192.168.219.101:8081');

  var payload = await rSocket.requestResponse!(routeAndDataPayload("healthcheck", "data!!!"));

  print(payload.getDataUtf8());

  rSocket.close();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

How can i receive this message in flutter?

I wanna make controller "chat.receive" route in flutter.

if java code,

```
@MessageMapping("chat.receive")
```

but i don't know flutter's @MessageMapping...

Comment: did you mange to get it working with the solution proposed by Mahdi Amini? If so, how did you handle JWT Auth?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that `rsocket: ^1.0.0.` is not working properly and you need to use

```
rsocket:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:rsocket/rsocket-dart.git
      ref: master
```

instead.

Then you can create a Futute like below as you connection holder:

```
  final Future<RSocket> _rsocketConnectionStream = RSocketConnector.create()
      .keepAlive(2000, 999999999)
      .connect('ws://192.168.1.188:8080')
      .catchError((error) => print(error));
```

Now you can make RSokcet calls like this:

```
  Payload routeAndDataPayload(String route, String data) {
    var compositeMetadata =
        CompositeMetadata.fromEntries([RoutingMetadata(route, List.empty())]);
    var metadataBytes = compositeMetadata.toUint8Array();
    var dataBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(data));
    return Payload.from(metadataBytes, dataBytes);
  }

  Stream<String?> fetchSeekersNames(String name, double latitude, double longitude, double searchingRadius) {
    var body = """
    {
      "location": {
          "latitude": $latitude,
          "longitude": $longitude
        },
        "radius": $searchingRadius,
        "dancerPartnerSeekerName": "$name"
    }
  """;
    return _rsocketConnectionStream
        .asStream()
        .asyncExpand((rSocket) => rSocket.requestStream!(
            routeAndDataPayload("/api/XXXX", body)))
        .map((element) => element!.getDataUtf8())
        .doOnError((p0, p1) => print(p1));
  }
```

I couldn't do it without `routeAndDataPayload` method. I wrote it after days of research.

There is no @MessageMapping equivalent in Dart as far as I know.
The `RSocket` library doesn't support Bi-Directional Channels.

But if you are trying make your flutter code keep the RSocket base connection, and do `request-stream` on top of it, I haven't been able to pull that out.

I couldn't make it work over TCP. I had to use webSocket for my RSocket underlying transport. But how to keep that websocket/rsocket connection ongoing in flutter code, .... !?

Please write here in case you found something.
All in all, I'm also

Comment: examples are from https://github.com/bmd007/wonderland/blob/master/api-gateway/src/main/java/wonderland/api/gateway/resource/DancePartnerFinderResource.java

Comment: and https://github.com/bmd007/wonderland/blob/master/dance_partner_finder/lib/client/api_gateway_rsocket_client.dart